# How to calculate OR (odd ratio) if one of groups is "0" in a case-control study in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R I am using epicalc package to calculate Odds Ratio.
I have this data

## Real values

```
values <- matrix(c(5,0,35,2,30,38,40,8,11,7,10,9,35,8,66,72,34,4,31,14), nrow = 2)
values
colnames(values) <- c("Laikipia", "West Pokot", "Garissa", "Isiolo", "Mandera", "Marsabit", "Samburu", "Tana River", "Turkana","Wajir")
rownames(values) <- c("0","1")
values <- as.table(values)
values
cc(outcome=NULL, exposure=NULL, cctable=values)}
```

But I am getting infinite for Odds Ratio that is pretty understandable as I am having one Zero value in Laikipia. So I tried the Haldane-Anscombe correction and added 0.5 in each cell code is given below but still I am getting infinite values

## Haldane-Anscombe correction

```
values1 <- matrix(c(5.5,0.5,35.5,2.5,30.5,38.5,40.5,8.5,11.5,7.5,10.5,9.5,35.5,8.5,66.5,72.5,34.5,4.5,31.5,14.5), nrow = 2)
values1
colnames(values1) <- c("Laikipia", "West Pokot", "Garissa", "Isiolo", "Mandera", "Marsabit", "Samburu", "Tana River", "Turkana","Wajir")
rownames(values1) <- c("O","1")
values <- as.table(values1)
values1
cc(outcome=NULL, exposure=NULL, cctable=values1)
```

"cc {epicalc}" Odds ratio calculation and graphing

```
Description

Odds ratio calculation and graphing

Usage

cc(outcome, exposure, decimal = 2, cctable = NULL, graph = TRUE, 
    original = TRUE, design = "cohort", main, xlab = "auto", ylab,
  alpha = .05, fisher.or = FALSE, exact.ci.or = TRUE)
```

How to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the documentation, `cctable` must be a 2x2 table. Your transformation of `values` is not a 2x2 table.

Comment: Nops, it worked when we don't have zero or decimal values, the problem is something linked to zero ord decimal values Thanks